# how can we add watermark to an existing html file

Tags: html, css

Is there any way to add water mark for an existing html file..  I have below code in html file

```html
<html>

<body>

  <h1>The position property</h1>

  <h2>position: static;</h2>
  <p>The Parent1 element has position: static, and will remain in the natural flow of the page. It will NOT act as anchor point for the absolutely positioned Child1 element:</p>

  <h2>position: relative;</h2>
  <p>The Parent2 element has position: relative, and will remain in the natural flow of the page. It will also act as anchor point for the absolutely positioned Child2 element:</p>

</body>

</html>
```

When i tried to add water mark by using below code , water mark is getting added at top of the html file or the bottom but its not getting applied as backend of content of the html file, is there any way i can try pls

```html
<html>
<style type="text/css">
  #watermark {
    color: #d0d0d0;
    font-size: 100pt;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    position: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 100;
    z-index: -2;
    left: -200px;
    top: -200px;
  }
</style>
<div id="watermark">
  <p>Insurance</p>
</div>

</html>
```

Comment: "backend of content" - What is the "backend"? Do you mean it's not going behind the other content? "Backend" almost always means the backend of a website/web server.

Comment: @GalaxyCat105 .. I mean back of the html file

Answer (score 3):

Position: absolute

```css
#watermark {
  color: #d0d0d0;
  font-size: 100pt;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  position: absolute;
  top:-175px;
  left: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 100;
  z-index: -2;


}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div>

    <h1>The position property</h1>

    <h2>position: static;</h2>
    <p>The Parent1 element has position: static, and will remain in the natural flow of the page. It will NOT act as anchor point for the absolutely positioned Child1 element:</p>

    <h2>position: relative;</h2>
    <p>The Parent2 element has position: relative, and will remain in the natural flow of the page. It will also act as anchor point for the absolutely positioned Child2 element:</p>

    <div id="watermark">
      <p>Insurance</p>
    </div>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I think you also need to stress that basically, have any `position` other than `static`. `position: center` also isn't a valid rule.

Comment: Would be even better if you set `user-select` to `none`.

Comment: @mplunghan .. I have one doubt , if i have multiple html open and close tags , can we apply water mark in the backened ?

Answer (score 2):

Basically, you should make the watermark div absolute and use flex to center the text both horizontally and vertically.

Try these settings:

```html
<html>
<style type="text/css">
  #watermark {
    position: absolute;
    top:0;bottom:0;left:0;right:0;
    display:flex;
    align-items:center;
    justify-content:center;
    overflow:hidden;
    z-index:-9;
  }
  #watermark > div {
   color: #d0d0d0;
   font-size: 100pt;
   opacity: .5;
   -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
   -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  }
</style>
<div id="watermark">
<div>Insurance</div>
</div>
<div>Page content Page content Page content Page content Page content Page content Page content Page content Page content Page content Page content Page content Page content Page content Page content Page content Page content Page content Page content Page content Page content Page content Page content Page content Page content Page content Page content Page content Page content Page content Page content Page content Page content Page content </div>
</html>
```

Comment: @ I have one doubt , if i have multiple html open and close tags , can we apply water mark in the backened ?

Comment: Yes, just use `class="watermark"` instead of id and you can use it multiple times.